# Client for uWebSockets

Tags: c++, client-server, uwebsockets

I'm using primarily C++ and want to implement server-client communication for a project. While not well-versed in distributed computing, I've tried various tool combinations like SocketIO server (in JS) + a C++ client library, or IXWebSocket. I also don't want to implement everything from scratch in Boost.Asio.

From what I've managed to find out, [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets) is the most performant and standards compliant solution for C++. The problem is that only a server library is available. I understand that "any" compliant web socket implementation will be able to work with the uWebSockets server, but:

- Is there a canonical approach? What do people use as a client in this case? I see the repo has ~12k stars so this must be pretty straightforward. Again I want to use a **C++ client**, not the browser implementation in JS.
- If a custom solution is appropriate, how should I go about it?

Comment: Alex Hultman (author of uWebSockets) in 2020 asked for donations to implement client support in uWebSockets past v0.14 on https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/issues/791 : "If you want client support, you can order it by paying for contracting hours required to make this happen. I would say 2 weeks or less." As of February 2022, it seems, this didn't happen yet.